# Power shell using the Trim function

Tags: powershell, trim

HI I have the following line to check variables from two different systems.

```
foreach ($val in $stafflist)
    {
     $found = 0
     foreach ($user in $aduser)
     if ((($val.Surname.trim() -eq $user.surname.trim()) -And ($val.'First Name'.trim() -eq $user.Givenname.trim())) -or (($val.Surname.trim() -eq $user.surname.trim()) -And ($val.'Known As'.trim() -eq $user.Givenname.trim())))
      {
       $found = 1
            try
                {
                if ($user.EmployeeID -ne $null) 
                    {

                    $val.'First Name' + " " + $val.'Known As' + " " + $val.surname + " EmployeedID already set as " + $user.EmployeeID | Out-File $outfile -Append 
                                    }

                else
                    {
                    set-aduser -Identity $user -EmployeeID $val.'Person Number'

                    $val.'First Name' + " " + $val.'Known As' + " " + $val.surname + " Employeed set to " + $user.EmployeeID| Out-File $outfile -Append
                                    }
     } ## end of Try
Catch 
     {
      $val.'First Name' +" " + $val.surname + "Can not be updated in AD" | Out-File $outfile -Append 
      }
}
```

So this checks each user in two lists ($stafflist and $aduser) against each other searching for matches, and when it finds a match it updates the employee ID in Active directory with the ID from the HR database.

The trouble is it has an or operator in it to account for the fact that in the HR database system either the "first name" or "known as name" or indeed both might be filled in and need to be checked.

I want to use the .Trim function in case some one has left in white spaces, but it throws and error if i place it against a variable and that variable end up as null, which is often the case with the "known as name" variable.

Can any one suggest the most efficient way to do this check and trim for each variable.

I could trim all the variables upfront after checking they are not null.
or test if they are null and if so pass them through different test strings to avoid errors but that all means more lines of code and slower execution of code.

If any one has a concise way to achieve this I would be grateful for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I am just adding this to the start of the loop

```
  if ($val.Surname -eq $null){} else {$val.Surname = $val.Surname.trim()}
if ($val.'First Name' -eq $null){} else {$val.'First Name' = $val.'First Name'.trim()}
if ($val.'Known As' -eq $null){} else {$val.'Known As' = $val.'Known As'.trim()}
```

So it early on checks for null values if not null trims it and stores it back to the variable.